# Why my multiprocessing code doesn't entering the condition?

Tags: python

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import requests
from config.config import *


def f(data):
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, data=data, verify=False, timeout=15)
        if r"Success" in response.text:
            logs = open('logs.txt', "a")
            logs.write('success\n')
            logs.close()
    except Exception as e:
        open('logs/errors.txt', "a").write('error\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(10):
        data = {'color': 'red', 'tool': 'brush'}
        Process(target=f, args=(data, )).start()
```

Why my code doesn't see the condition `if r"Success" in response.text:` ?
**Even** if I trying with `if True:`

What the reason of that behavior and how to prevent it ?

Comment: You might first check if `response.text` is really a string. Or shouldn't it be `response.text()`?

Comment: Deos that depend on whether you're using multiprocessing or not?

Comment: Add `print(repr(response.text))` and see what's in it? That would answer your question immediately. Also, have you checked `logs/errors.txt` to see if it's growing?

Comment: Is this code complete? Because if so, `url` is not defined anywhere. I get not wanting to reveal specifics of the servers you interact with, but making it a [MCVE] that works against some public server would make it much easier for others to reproduce and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test

```py
        if r"Success" in response.text:
```

presupposes that the HTTP request is successful, but it (or the preceding `post`) can fail and can raise an exception for a number of reasons. When an exception occurs, the program will jump to the `except` block (which I would guess is what is happening), resulting in no output to logs.txt.

I would add [response.raise_for_status](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) before checking the text.

Also, it might be a good idea to print the error to diagnose it later. (This is optional.)

So the function `f` would look like:

```py
def f(data):
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, data=data, verify=False, timeout=15)
        response.raise_for_status() # raise exception for failed requests
        if r"Success" in response.text:
            logs = open('logs.txt', "a")
            logs.write('success\n')
            logs.close()
    except Exception as e:
        # output the content of the error, e
        open('logs/errors.txt', "a").write(f'error: {e}\n')
```

Comment: So, why it doesn’t entering to the if True: block though? (W/o raise_for_status)

Comment: It Works like it’s throwing all 10 requests and somehow not even see the condition block below

Comment: In that case,  ``post`` might be raising an exception. (I modified the answer to cover that.)